# Neo4J admin import list property

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher

Can I import a relationship property of type list using the `neo4j-admin import` tool?

The cypher query would look something like this:

```
MERGE (a:A {name: "a"})
MERGE (b:B {name: "b"})
CREATE (a)-[r:N { items: [1, 2, 3] }]-(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`neo4j-admin` supports `--array-delimiter` which can be used to separate single fields in an array.

NOTE: the column header needs to include the array data hint!

The example above would be imported with:

```
Id:ID   name    :LABEL
a   a   A
b   b   B
```

```
:START_ID   :END_ID items:string[]  :TYPE
a   b   1|2|3   N
```

`neo4j-admin import --delimiter='TAB' --array-delimiter='|' ...`